# JDBC Select * from user_table throws error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to make a java program that checks usernames and passwords against my database and currently the code throws an error stating:

> Multiple markers at this line
>
> - The operator * is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String,     java.lang.String
> - Syntax error on token "passedpassword", * expected

here is the code:

```
public class Authenticate {

public static void AuthorizeUser(String passedusername, char[] passedpassword) {

    DBConnector.Connect();

    Statement stmt = null;

     try {
           if (passedusername != null && passedpassword !=null) {
           String sql = "Select * from users_table Where username='" + passedusername + "' and password='"passedpassword "'";
           ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
           if( rs.next()){
                //in this case enter when at least one result comes it means user is valid
               System.out.println("user valid");
           } else {
                //in this case enter when  result size is zero  it means user is invalid
               System.out.println("User Fraudulent");
           }
       }

    //You can also validate user by result size if its comes zero user is invalid else user is valid


        } catch (SQLException err) {
            System.out.println(err.getMessage());
        }

    DBConnector.Close();


}

}
```

I know it is probably a small and simple mistake but Im fairly new to JBDC and java and I can not figure it out.

Edit: Question resolved was missing two +. Upon correction of the original error a NullPointerException error is thrown due to the fact that stmt is null. This will be fixed later as i am working to solve a error that is caused by me  defining stmt as:

```
Statement stmt = null;
conn = DBConnector.conn;
```

the error given is:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.sql.Statement to com.mysql.jdbc.Statement

I have also been informed that i should use PreparedStatement to prevent sql Injection

Comment: Use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Comment: you miss +  in concatenating string password

Comment: and yet again i feel like an idiot! thank you

Comment: After you fix the concatenation problem you will get a `NullPointerException` because `stmt` is `null`. Also, you should use a `PreparedStatement` for this.

Comment: @Titus I was aware of the NullPointerException error working to resolve that next as for the PreparedStatement I have seen a lot about this but am not sure on what this is for or how it is done but will be reading into it. Thank you

Comment: `PreparedStatement` is usually used when you need to create SQL statements from user input, and it is used to prevent SQL injection [more details](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try this
you should use `passedpassword` between  `'"+  +"'"`

```
String sql = "Select * from users_table Where username='" + passedusername + "' and password='"+passedpassword+"'";
```

Comment: wow the simplest things and they can be the hardest to catch. thank you